Speed up this python script that prints all UNIQUE partitions of a number in python
This code is doing a lot of unnecessary processing. For ex, for the number 3, one of its partitions is 1+1+1, but it keeps finding '1+1+1's even after the first one. There are a total of 6. How to stop it after the first one?

def perm(a,k=0):
    if k==len(a):
        permstr=''
        for i in range(len(a)):
            permstr=permstr+str(a[i])
        if int(permstr) not in permslist:
            permslist.append(int(permstr))
    else:
        for i in range(k,len(a)):
            a[k],a[i] =a[i],a[k]
            perm(a,k+1)
            a[k],a[i] =a[i],a[k]
         
def sumways(n,size,limit):
    if limit is None:
        limit=n
    if size==1:
        if n<=limit:
            yield[n]
    else:
        for i in range(0,limit+1):
            for tail in sumways(n-i,size-1,min(i,n-i)):
                yield[i]+tail

m=11
for n in range(1,1+m):
    permslist=[]
    sums=list(sumways(n,n,n))
    for i in range(len(sums)):
        sums[i]=[j for j in sums[i] if j!=0]
        if perm(sums[i])!=None:
            perm=(perm(sums[i]))
    maxave=0
    for i in range(len(permslist)):
        ave=0
        for j in range(len(str(permslist[i]))):
            ave=ave+int(str(permslist[i])[j])
        ave=ave/(1+j)
        if ave>maxave:
            maxave=ave
            maxaveat=permslist[i]
    print(n,len(permslist),maxave,maxaveat,permslist)
    print()



Have you considered recursion. The partitions of three see a lot like one partition of three combined with the partitions of 2

What would you like the partitions of 3 to be, and does order matter? If order matters then use bars and stars and count in binary to place the bars.

You can just use the "stars and bars" approach to partition a number.
For example, m = 3:
1 + 1 + 1
  |   |         <- possible positions of a bar

A bar (which splits up the partition) is placed if a binary bit is 1, otherwise omitted. So, you just count up to 11b (which is 2^(m-1)-1) in binary to get all the partitions without any repetition.
This assumes that 1+2 is different from 2+1, for example.
m = int( input( "Enter m: " ) )
for p in range( 1 << ( m - 1 ) ):      # count to 2^(m-1)-1 in binary
    a = 1
    for pos in range( m - 1 ):
        if p & ( 1 << pos ):           # actually, reverse binary: not that it matters
            print( a, end='+' )
            a = 1
        else:
            a += 1
    print( a )

e.g. for m = 3
Enter m: 3
3
1+2
2+1
1+1+1


Beautiful! Thank you. How did you get this solution? And yes, the solution I needed DOES treat 1+2 as different from 2+1, but not 1+1+1 as different from 1+1+1.

I didn’t get this particular solution from anywhere in particular - just composed it on the spot - but the “stars and bars” approach is a very common technique for combinatorics, particularly since it goes so well with binary.

one interesting thing I noticed is that if I comment out print(a), and replace end='+' with end='', then the print output collapses the sums such that the digits in the next sum are reused if they match. how does that happen? it's interesting. another thing is, is there a way to only generate sums of desired length? for example for 3, and length=2, it will skip giving me the three ones and just give 2+1 and 1+2. and again, thanks a lot it is faster than the previous solution. by the way, it seems that under these constraints, the number of unique sums is simple 2^n. lol

If you replace end='+' with end='' then you will simply remove any gaps and newlines. You don't have to print out all the numbers: you can simply put them in a list if you prefer. If you want those of a specific length then just reject the others. The number of unique partitions is - by the construction method embodied in the code, just 2^(m-1), since there are m-1 positions where you can put a bar (or not).
